# Android static percentage bar view - not a progress bar

Tags: android, listview, android-framelayout

I'm trying to show items in a ListView like so:

```
    a. Name1
        80.33 ======      60%

    b. Name2
       101.22 =======     70%

    c. Name3
        55.22 ===         30%

    d. Name4
       140.11 ========== 100%
```

The "graph" should be a solid colored line but the entire width of the 100% needs to be there, and it should occupy the entire width available except for the value on the far left and the percentage on the far right.  Also the percentages are more percentiles, relative to the lowest value in the set!

Anyway I have tried a FrameLayout with a ProgressBar and that seems to be ill-suited for this plus I can't get it to lay out the way I want.  I'm thinking a 1px colored image that I stretch the percent I need then a 1px dark image the rest of the way.

Any ideas?  My thanks!

EDIT:
ok progress but a new problem:

Here's what I did in the layout:

```
    <View
        android:id="@+id/pr_bar_1"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="4dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/pr_bar_2"
        android:layout_width="70dip"
        android:layout_height="4dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#333333" />
```

That looks exactly like what I want!  However... I can't seem to set the widths dynamically now.  There is no `setLayoutWidth(int dip)` method for the View class.  If I could get that then I'd be done.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Edited to include new solution... and new problem.

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you need to show dark line for scored percentage. Let me correct if i am wrong. For that you can try this:-

You can use 2 **LinearLayout** under 1 horizontal **LinearLayout** Parent. Set the **Weightsum** of parent Layout to 100. First LinearLayout which comes in left with dark image and second with light image. Then set the weight of left child according to percent, and give remaining percent to right **LinearLayout**

Answer for your edit question:

```
LayoutParams     
 params=view_instan.getLayoutParams();
params.width=yourWidth;
view_instan.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  In the mean time I found a solution (above in EDIT) but as I describe now I have a new problem: can't dynamically set a View's layout_width, argh! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that custom, write your own view and override onDraw to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using view.setLayoutParams(params) didn't work for me, I had to put the code inside a runnable.

xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="6dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingStart="1dp"
    android:paddingEnd="1dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pr_bar_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/blue">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pr_bar_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/white">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

java:

```
final int percentage = my_percentage;
llParent.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int fullWidth = llParent.getWidth();

                prBar2.getLayoutParams().width = Math.round(fullWidth*((1 - ((float) (percentage/100)))));
                prBar2.requestLayout();
                prBar1.getLayoutParams().width = Math.round(fullWidth*((float) (percentage/100)));
                prBar1.requestLayout();
            }
        });
```